# How to delete Item as Resource ( IAR ) from XM - Cloud?

Tags: xm-cloud

I created a Page in XM Cloud, and now I am unable to delete the page, It is showing a warning message
Some items are in resources and cannot be deleted.

[image]

And now after refreshing the screen, the page items are still there. (restored from resources)
After investigating I found out that the items are created as IAR, but now the question is how? I only made a simple page how did it get stored in the resource?

How are items automatically created as IAR (items as resources) in XM – Cloud?

And how to delete these items from XM Cloud?

Comment: Did you deploy the IAR file? What's the path and does your SCS module.json include this path when the IAR generation runs?

Answer (score 2):

IAR items are created as part of your serialization. That page will be included in your source control as a serialized item. The only way to delete it would be to remove the item from source control and redeploy your application.

Answer (score 1):

The warning message you are seeing in XM Cloud, indicating that some items are in resources and cannot be deleted, is likely due to the fact that these items have been serialized and stored as part of the configuration using Sitecore Content Serialization (SCS). This means that the items are saved as .yml files and have become part of the serialized configuration in XM Cloud.

It's important to note that once items are included in the serialization, they cannot be deleted directly from XM Cloud because they are considered part of the configuration.

To delete these items from XM Cloud, you will need to exclude them from the serialization config and redeploy your configuration to XM Cloud.